# Shortcut to open table schema in new tab by clicking on table name in BigQuery editor

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following in the BigQuery editor:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

I remember there used to be a shortcut similar to CMD+CLICK on the table name that would open the properties of `table` in a new tab showing the table schema, details and preview.

Is it gone or how do you do it?

EDIT:
Apparently the feature works again once you "DISABLE EDITOR TABS" at the top of the BigQuery console. Looks like this is a missing feature when editor tabs are enabled.

EDIT2:
Looks like the feature is working again also when editor tabs are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the feature works again once you "DISABLE EDITOR TABS" at the top of the BigQuery console. Looks like this is a missing feature when editor tabs are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enclose your table with using **``** and then use `CMD` + `CLICK`.

You can refer to this GCP documentation for the complete list of keyboard shortcuts in Bigquery:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#keyboard_shortcuts

Comment: The table is actually enclosed using ``. I edited my question. The GCP documentation doesn't include any pointer to what I'm looking for.